# Merge into a select statement - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, merge

Is it possible to filter some of the entries to be merged on a table using select?

```
MERGE INTO (
  SELECT * FROM P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA
  WHERE ( CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT <> 0 )
)  ta
USING P4DAS2_DONARTSTK tb ON (tb.NUM_ID_PDT =ta.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT)    
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET ta.COD_SECVTE_REVENT=tb.COD_SECVTE_REVENT);
```

Comment: I was asked to do a query like this and I can't get it to work although I'm said it's possible.

Comment: "*Can't get it to work*" is not a valid Oracle error message.

Comment: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle you  can execute DML on (some) views or subqueries. The guideline is that if Oracle is able to retrieve the physical row from the view, the view is updateable.

You can therefore use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) on a subquery. It makes sense in some cases. For example suppose you have a table with a status column. You want to merge new information into this table, but only modify the rows that have `STATUS='active'`. You could write:

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status='active') old
     USING (SELECT * FROM newtable) new
        ON (new.id = old.id)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET old.data1=new.data1;
```

#### Edit

It appears that this produces an `ORA-00903` in 9iR2. It works in 11g though. Test script:

```
create table t (id number, c varchar2(10));
insert into t (select rownum, 'aaa' from dual connect by level <= 1000);
merge into (select * from t where id <= 10) t 
     using (select 1 id from dual) d 
        ON (t.id = d.id) 
      when matched then update set c = 'iii';
```

Comment: Does it work on Oracle 10g? the error is ORA-00903: invalid table name (always)

Comment: You're right it doesn't seem to work on all versions of Oracle. I tried it first on 11gr2 and it works fine. On 9ir2 it produces an ORA-903 also.

Comment: does it speed up the merge if I am filtering the INTO target table?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
MERGE INTO P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA ta
USING (
  select tb.*
  from P4DAS2_DONARTSTK tb
    join P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA ta on tb.NUM_ID_PDT = ta.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT
  where ta.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT <> 0 
) t ON (t.NUM_ID_PDT =ta.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT)    
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  update set ta.COD_SECVTE_REVENT=tb.COD_SECVTE_REVENT;
```

Not sure I got the join for the `USING` part correct based on your example.

The basic idea is to only select the rows you want to update inside the USING clause, not as part of the INTO clause.

Answer (score 0):

A hacktastic workaround for versions below 11g:

Create a package to hold variable values:

```
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_MY_VARIABLES 
as
  CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT number;
end;
/
```

Create a view referencing that package.

```
create or replace view V_P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA
as 
select * 
  from P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA 
 where CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT <> PKG_MY_VARIABLES.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT ;
```

Before running the merge statement, set the package variable to the value you want.

```
exec pkg_my_variables.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT := 0;
```

Run the merge against the view.

```
MERGE INTO V_P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA ta
USING P4DAS2_DONARTSTK tb ON (tb.NUM_ID_PDT =ta.CA_LIG_VTE_NUM_ID_PDT)    
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET ta.COD_SECVTE_REVENT=tb.COD_SECVTE_REVENT);
```